# How to sort by referenced name instead of column_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a list of items from a model (Records) that have a reference to a column from another model (Companies). In Records, I use `company_id` to reference the associated company. However when I sort, I don't want to use the `record.company_id`, but instead `record.company.name`. In my controller I use this to get the sort on the company_id:

```
@records = Record.all.order("company_id ASC")
```

That works just fine by sorting them by the `company_id`, but I want to sort them by the associated name. But when I do the following I get an undefined method error for name, which I know is not the correct syntax.

```
@records = Record.all.order(:company.name)
```

Q: How can I go about sorting by the associated company name?

---

Here is some of my corresponding code:

Record model

```ruby
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Company Model

```ruby
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end
```

Record controller (with incorrect statement)

```ruby
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @records = Record.all.order(:company.name)
  end
...
end
```

Company controller

```ruby
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end
...
end
```

Record index view

```erb
...
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= record.company.name %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
Record.includes(:company).order('companies.name') # no need to call `all`
```

Check out [Active Record Query Interface Giude](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more info.

Comment: I'm going to go with this one because it lists the rows where there are no companies, whereas the other one omits them.

Comment: @Reveren it is because my answer uses `includes`, which corresponds to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in sql, whereas John's `joins` corresponds to `INNER JOIN` in sql. Just so you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Record.joins(:company).merge(Company.order(:name))
```